# Neo4Django - KeyError: 'GremlinPlugin' error while creating an object

Tags: django, python-2.7, neo4j, neo4django

I'm trying to learn to work with `Neo4j`database in my django projects. I installed `Neo4Django` from `github` repository. and following its [neo4j tutorial](https://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) when I try to create a new object from my model I encounter with this error:

> KeyError: 'GremlinPlugin'

I'm using `Python 2.7`, `Django Version 1.5.8`, `Pycharm 3`

My model is:

```
class Movie(models.NodeModel):
    # name of the movie
    title = models.StringProperty()
```

and my console code for creating the object is:

```
from nodes_app.models import Movie
movie = Movie.objects.create(title='a')
```

and this is the console output for the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\manager.py", line 43, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\query.py", line 1307, in create
    return super(NodeQuerySet, self).create(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\query.py", line 416, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in save
    return super(NodeModel, self).save(using=using, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.8-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 546, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\base.py", line 341, in save_base
    self._save_neo4j_node(using)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _save_neo4j_node
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\base.py", line 98, in trans_method
    ret = func(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\db\models\base.py", line 369, in _save_neo4j_node
    typesToIndex=type_names_to_index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\neo4jclient.py", line 179, in gremlin_tx
    return self.gremlin(script, tx=True, **params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django-0.1.8-py2.7.egg\neo4django\neo4jclient.py", line 127, in gremlin
    ext = self.extensions.GremlinPlugin
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4jrestclient\client.py", line 2176, in __getattr__
    self._dict[attr] = ExtensionModule(self._extensions[attr], self._auth)
KeyError: 'GremlinPlugin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Neo4j Django driver depends on the `Gremlin` plugin on the Neo4j server. Starting with Neo4j 2.0, Gremlin has been removed from the distribution but is still available as a [contribution package](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin), see the instructions there.

Comment: I installed the `windows` distribution. So I need to compile neo4j from its source?

Comment: no, you just need to download the contrib package, build it and install it as documented.